# UpdatePanel in upgraded project vs new 3.5 project

Tags: asp.net, ajax, .net-3.5, webforms

I can get an UpdatePanel control working(partial postbacks) no problem with a new fresh .net 3.5 project.  I've overcome many of the pitfalls that are answered here on this site.  (scriptmanager on the page, using triggers, or placing the button within the panel itself.)

If I have try to use the UpdatePanel on a project that was originally a .net 1.1 project, upgraded to 2.0, now recently upgraded to 3.5, I can't get partial post backs for anything.  At this point the code is exactly the same within the form.  My relevant web.config parts are the same, and from what I can tell my .proj files too are the same.

Anyone have any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure you aren't still caching the assemblies?  I know the AJAX control toolkit required you to "copy local".  Make sure you eliminate that as a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked, and the copy local is set to false on all references.  Any other check to see if caching is a problem?